# How do you see the row groups of your files in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I came across this [page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1337) in jira, and I'd like to know how to get that same view of the row groups. Like this:

[image]

Is there a command in hdfs that can show this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported that JIRA. I used

```
parquet-tools meta /path/to/file.parquet | grep "row group"
```

and then edited the output by hand to align the numbers. Alternatively, you can append `| column -t` for some basic alignment. Although numbers will be left-aligned in this case instead of being right-aligned, at least they will line up one under the other.

`parquet-tools` itself is an undocumented helper script [included](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-tools/src/main/scripts/parquet-tools) in parquet-mr. Instead of using that you can just call

```
hadoop jar /path/to/parquet-tools-<VERSION>.jar
```

on a Hadoop cluster or

```
java -jar /path/to/parquet-tools-<VERSION>.jar
```

locally. For the latter, you have to build parquet using the local profile, i.e.,

```
mvn package -Plocal
```

This is described in the [build instructions](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools#build).

Comment: I built parquet tools from the source, but it seems that I have to use a java command to run the built jar. How do you get the parquet-tools executable like that?

Comment: `parqet-tools` is just a shell script that does the same. I extended my answer with details about this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its an output of `parquet-tools` sifted through `grep`, like

```
  $ parquet-tools meta --debug <file-name> | grep "row group"
```